# indexLink in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Is there a new way to use indexLink in React Router v4?  I am updating some version 3 code.

I'm bringing it in with some destructuring:

```
var {NavLink, IndexLink} = require('react-router-dom');
```

and using IndexLink to keep it from being bold all the time:

```
<h2>Nav</h2>
<IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>blah blah blah</IndexLink>
//Other navlinks working fine
```

IndexLink is the only thing breaking my code, here is an error from when I change it to that.

> "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `Nav`."

Everything is exported, and the simple app works perfectly until I add IndexLink.  Now to pass out.

Comment: I'd really recommend having a proper read of the RRv4 docs - the API in the new version is fundamentally different.

Comment: burned me a time or two already

Comment: I definitely had a read before coming here. A 2 hour search through the docs and google on no sleep might not qualify as 'proper' though! :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<Indexlink>` doesn't exist in RRv4 because `<IndexRoute>` and the whole concept of indexes doesn't really exist in RRv4. Remember that Links and Routes are directly related.

So instead, just use `<NavLink>`.

Have a read about [**NavLink**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) on the official docs:

> **`NavLink`** -  A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

If you need more control over the URL matching, you can use the `strict` or `exact` props.

Comment: Thanks! I still have to fix it, but that's the gist of what I needed to know.  I actually had it as Navlink before trying IndexLink.  Could have been sleep deprivation, but I could't find that index was gone in the documentation.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 12):

Per Chris, the correct answer was to continue to use NavLink and use **exact**.  Strict did not work in this case.

```
<NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>chris is awesome</NavLink>
```

Just in case another comes across this!